# Why calculator works incorrectly?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my first calculator with vanilla JS. My logic is the following.

- You click on a number(1/2)
- you hit on a sign (plus/minus)
- you click on a second number
- you hit equals and get an answer.

My equals button gets different functions through plus and minus. However, it does not work properly. `1 - 2 = -1` but then when you do `+2` it gets `-3` instead of `1`.

What is wrong?

```js
var screen = document.getElementById('hres');
var numI = 0;
var numII = 0;

document.getElementById('one').addEventListener("click", uno);

function uno() {
  screen.value = 1;
}

document.getElementById('two').addEventListener("click", duo);

function duo() {
  screen.value = 2;
}

function plus() {
  numI = screen.value;
  document.getElementById('eql').addEventListener('click', equalP);
}

function equalP() {
  numII = screen.value;
  screen.value = +numI + +numII;
}

function minus() {
  numI = screen.value;
  document.getElementById('eql').addEventListener('click', equalM);
}

function equalM() {
  numII = screen.value;
  screen.value = numI - numII;
}
```

```css
#hres {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 22pt;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

#sum {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20pt;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

#one {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20pt;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#two {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20pt;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#eql {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20pt;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  transition: .3s;
}

#sub {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20pt;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<input id="hres" readonly></input><br>
<div id="one">1</div>
<div id="two">2</div><br>
<button onclick="plus()" id="sum">+</button>
<button onclick="minus()" id="sub">-</button>
<button id="eql">=</button>
```

Comment: 1 - 2 = -1 but then when you do +2 it gets -3 instead of 1. Have you checked that?

Comment: You keep adding those event handlers, which means all those calculations are run multiple times when you click the equals button. Here's a fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5cqjvwnt/

Comment: Add `console.log` to both `equalP` and `equalM` and you'll see what @ChrisG is talking about.

Comment: @musefan The calculations actually work, once the adding multiple handlers is fixed.

Comment: A side question: what is the goal of `screen.value = +numI + +numII;`?

Comment: @reporter otherwise it will be treated as a string and 2 + 1 will be equals to 21

Comment: @ChrisG thanx a lot! I knew there is some simpler way to handle all this stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all lets identify the problems:

1. You are registering the event listener for the equals button *every* time you click plus or minus. This means the event function will run as many times as it is registered and will effect your results
2. You are not re-adjusting your variables. After equals you want numI to become the new total, so that you can store the next operation value in num2 and then perform the correct calculation on equals

To achieve this requires a fair bit of refactoring of your code. I have highlighted the important bits with comments:

```
// Register all events once, and once only.
document.getElementById('sum').addEventListener("click", plus);
document.getElementById('sub').addEventListener("click", minus);
document.getElementById('eql').addEventListener('click', equal);
document.getElementById('one').addEventListener("click", uno);
document.getElementById('two').addEventListener("click", duo);

// Get input element for display purposes.
var screen = document.getElementById('hres');

// Variables to hold the numbers we are working with, and the operation symbol.
var numI = 0;
var numII = 0;
var operation = null;

// Simple functions to handle each number button.
// You could use a data-* attribute and have a sinle generic function.
function uno() {
  setNumber(1);
}

function duo() {
  setNumber(2);
}

// Function that processes any number provided.
// The key here is to check if the user has click an operations button,
// if so then we want to set the second variable. Otherwise set the first.
function setNumber(n) {
  screen.value = n;
  if (operation)
    numII = n;
  else
    numI = n;
}

// Basic functions to set the operation type. Again, data-* attribute would be useful.
function plus() {
  operation = '+';
}

function minus() {
  operation = '-';
}

// Function to calculate result.
// Here we check what the operation is and apply the correct logic to match.
// Importantly, at the end, we assign the result to numI so it is ready for the next operation.
function equal() {
  var result = 'err';
  if (operation == '+')
    result = numI + numII;
  else if (operation == '-')
    result = numI - numII;
  numI = result;
  screen.value = result;
}
```

[Here is a working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/57L8cxae/)

---

NOTE: Even with these changes their isn't any validation on user input. It very much relies on the user pressing buttons in the correct order (i.e. number > operation > number > equals > operation/number, etc.). You should consider this if you want to further improve your code, it would be out of scope for me to provide that as an answer to this question though.